# Mongodb update array in array

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to update this document:

```
  {
    "user_id": "60800ba9a9ccaf160e385612",
    "date": "2021-03-20",
    "data": [
      [
        {
          "type": "blind_mouse",
          "count": 1,
          "played_count": 0
        },
        {
          "type": "color_and_shape_matching",
          "count": 1,
          "played_count": 0
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "type": "thieves_and_police",
          "count": 3,
          "played_count": 0
        },
        {
          "type": "boat",
          "count": 3,
          "played_count": 0
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Actually, update `played_count` where `type` equal by "blind_mouse".

I tried this query but it won't work:

```php
$collection_games_delivered->updateOne(
    ['user_id' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USERID'], 'date' => $date, 'data.$.type' => $type],
    [
        '$set' => ['data.$.played_count' => $played_count]
    ]
);
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- update part, `$[]` for first level array and `$` for positional matching `type`
- use arrayFilters to update positional element, search for `type`

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  {
    user_id: "60800ba9a9ccaf160e385612",
    date: "2021-03-20"
  },
  { $set: { "data.$[].$[e].played_count": 1 } },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "e.type": "thieves_and_police" }
    ]
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8cj3lJ3S7FZ)

**PHP syntax:**

```php
$collection_games_delivered->updateOne(
  [
    'user_id' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USERID'], 
    'date' => $date
  ],
  [
    '$set' => ['data.$[].$[e].played_count' => $played_count]
  ],
  [
    'arrayFilters' => [
      'e.type' => 'thieves_and_police'
    ]
  ]
);
```

Comment: it's not working, it just updates the first element of the data array, but doesn't update the element with the type "boat"

Comment: probably you are missing something, share the new [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6tchKDKY659) link with your not working example.

Comment: I tried to update 'thieves_and_police' but 'color_and_shape_matching' was updated.
 https://mongoplayground.net/p/F7KhBpyJNfJ

Comment: you can check i have corrected the answer.